# Jquery slider with autoplay doesn't pause on final slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to make a simple slider which stays 5 secondes on each slide (4 elements per slide), then goes back to the first slide and run again.

The number of elements may vary from 1 to 16.

Right now, my slider doesn't pause on last slide. It goes straight back to the first one.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leosrds/nzyx3624/).

```js
var width = $(window).width();
var currentSlide = 1;
var $slides = $('ul li');
var itemNbr = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;

$(function() {
    if ( itemNbr > 4) {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('ul').animate({
                'margin-left' : '-='+width}, 700, function () {
                currentSlide++;
                if (currentSlide >= itemNbr/4) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $('ul').animate({
                        'margin-left' : '0px'},700
                    ); 
                };
            });
        },5000);
    };
});
```

Comment: you need to write a condition first setInterval function define in a variable and use clearInterval(variable name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your setInterval function this way :

```js
var width = $(window).width();
var currentSlide = 1;
var $slides = $('ul li');
var itemNbr = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;

$(function() {
    if ( itemNbr > 4) {
        setInterval(function () {
        if (currentSlide >= itemNbr/4) {
            $('ul').animate({'margin-left' : '0px'}, 700); 
            currentSlide = 1; // Edit
        }
        else {
            $('ul').animate({'margin-left' : '-='+width}, 700);
            currentSlide++;
        }
        },5000);
    };
});
```

```css
wrapper {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
  width:300vw; height:320px;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul li {
  width:80vw;
  height:60px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px 10vw;
  background-color:red;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<wrapper>
  <ul>
    <li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li><!--
    --><li>ITEM</li>
  </ul>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Actually the slider doesn't start again once it come back to the start... Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Oups, sorry, I forgot to reset currentSlide... I edited the snippet !

Comment: I could figure it out myself ! Thanks again ;)